# Pass ArrayList to JQuery Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2, flot

Good Afternoon.

English is not my native language so please be patient.

I'm a beginner in [see tags] and have a web app which collect a date and a serial to make a sql query and return some data (value from a measure and the date from the measure) to the Action doDrawFlot, in the action this data is formmated to populate a flot graph.

**I need an ArrayList<(String or Integer)> and pass it to Javascript to populate a flot graph.**

At this moment I have my Action:

```
public InputStream inputStream;

    public String doDrawFlot() {

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        response.append("1_20");
        response.append("2_50");
        response.append("3_10");

        byte[] bArray = response.toString().getBytes();
        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bArray); 

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Struts2 XML

```
<action name="GetProfile" class="com.raspberry.struts.action.PerfilCargaAction" 
        method="doDrawFlot">
    <interceptor-ref name="SessionValidationStack" />
    <result type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    </result>            
</action>
```

And the Javascript File:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Re-load records when user click 'load records' button.
    $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'GetProfile?fechaPerfil='+$('#startDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm' }).val()+'&meter=' + $('#meterList option:selected').text(),

        success: function (response) {
console.log(response);    //At request of @Raidri
            var servletResponse = response;

            var str = [];
            var num = [];
            var d1 = [];

            for (var i = 0, len = servletResponse.length; i < len; i++) {

                num.push(parseInt(servletResponse[i].split("_")[0])),
                str.push(parseInt(servletResponse[i].split("_")[1]));
                d1[i] = [num[i],str[i]];    
            }
console.log(d1);    //At request of @Raidri
            $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d1]);
        } 
        });       
        });
    $.plot($("#flotDiv"), [[]]);                
});
```

As you can see the data isn't in a ArrayList, this is because I'm using a inputstream to pass the data client side.

To pass the data like an array and formatting correctly in the flot is **absolutely necessary** to use Json (or Gson)?

**Or my current build can do the job?**

Any ideas (code fixes, POJOs, simple tutorials for a noob) or recomendations?

I'm using struts2 and the [mykong tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/) have not helped me.

**Update:**

At request of @Raidri the output of the two console logs:

console.log(response) : `1_202_503_10`

console.log(d1) : `[1,NaN][NaN,NaN][2,NaN][0,NaN][2, NaN][NaN,NaN][5,NaN][0,NaN][3,NaN][NaN,NaN][1,NaN][NaN,0]`

The stream send a single String, I need an array because the length of the measures could change (i.e. "102" or "0")

Comment: Please insert a `console.log(response)` at the beginning of the success callback function and a `console.log(d1)` before the `$.plot()` call and then add the results to your answer.

Comment: @Raidri Thanks for your comment, question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see your `d1` array is not valid. And your original data string needs some separator between the data points, for example

```
response.append("1_20;");
...

// response = "1_20;2_50;3_10"
```

Then we can use the `map()` function to build our data array like this:

```
d1 = response.split(';').map(function (datapoint) {
    return datapoint.split('_');
});

// d1 = [["1", "20"], ["2", "50"], ["3", "10"]]
```

Comment: Your answer has been most useful, but doesn't handle arrays. 
Still I was able to plot correctly my data with a little "work around" of your answer. If no body else answer with a method for arrays, I'll accept your answer. 

Once again thanks.

Comment: Thanks Raidri. Your answer help me to manage to have two "Yaxis" and display data vs time properly.